# Press enter to export Keyboard Hook message

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, keyboard-hook

I've written a program to get keyboard hook. What I want is, when a user presses Enter, the typed text, for example: "hello world", which I stored in `exportMsg`, should be returned from the function.

I want to make a dll and export `exportMsg`.

Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream> 
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam); 
HHOOK keyboardHook;
HWND prevWindow;
std::string exportMsg=""; 
int main()
{
    keyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardProc, 0, 0);
    MSG msg{ 0 };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0);
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(keyboardHook);
    return 0;
} 
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    wchar_t title[256];
    HWND fwindow = GetForegroundWindow();
    PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT key = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
    //a key was pressed
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN && nCode == HC_ACTION )
    { 
        //return if enter pressed
        if (key->vkCode == '\r')
        {  
            std::cout << exportMsg << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            exportMsg.push_back(key->vkCode);
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(keyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: The most important part of `SetWindowsHookEx` is the 3rd parameter, and you left it null.

Comment: @Andy how can I associate `exportMsg` to `SetWindowsHookEx ` to get the message?

Comment: You need the instance of the module the hook resides. So in your case it would be `GetModuleHandle(NULL)`. So you'd call it as so: `SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardProc, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0);`

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand the question. I thought i read it wasn't working at all. You *should* fill in the 3rd parameter, for sure. Could you re-phrase it to explain what you want to happen when they hit the enter key? You want it "exported to the DLL" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The issue is I want to eport  `exportMsg `, whenever the Enter key is pressed.

Comment: @Zues Do you want to export to a file or return the string every time you press ENTER?

Comment: @ZhuSong I want to return the string.

Comment: @Zues If you press the ENTER key randomly, does the function calling the DLL use multithreading?

Comment: @ZhuSong no, it's just a simple function, doesn't use multithreading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `std::cin` doesn't work in *Unity*, I needed to use Keyboard Hook to scan qrCode through a `QR Code Scanner Machine` and send the scanned string to the `Unity`.

This algorithm capture the key strokes and returns the string when Enter is pressed.

My DLL code looks like this:

Header file:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
HHOOK keyboardHook;
HWND prevWindow;
std::string exportMsg = "";

QRCODEREADER_EXPORTS_API void StartHook(char* str, int strlen);
```

Source file:

```
QRCODEREADER_EXPORTS_API void StartHook(char* str, int strlen)
{ 
    string result;
    cout << "please scan the QR code!!!\n";
    //std::cin >> result; 
    exportMsg.clear();

    HHOOK keyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardProc, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0);
    if (!keyboardHook) {
        std::cout << "Failed to hook keyboard\n";
    }
    else {
        MSG msg{ 0 };
        while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0);
         
        result = exportMsg;
        cout << "your data: " << result << "\n";

        result = result.substr(0, strlen);
        //str = new char[result.length()];
        std::copy(result.begin(), result.end(), str);
        str[min(strlen - 1, (int)result.size())] = 0;
    } 
     
    std::cout << "Quitting...\n"; 
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(keyboardHook); 
}
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HWND fwindow = GetForegroundWindow();
    PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT key = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
    //a key was pressed
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN && nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        //return if enter pressed
        if (key->vkCode == '\r')
        {
            std::cout << exportMsg << std::endl;
            PostQuitMessage(0); 
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(keyboardHook);
        }
        else
        {
            exportMsg.push_back(key->vkCode);
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(keyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

dllmain:

```
int main() {
    char* a;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        a = new char[50];
        StartHook(a, 50);
        cout<< i << "th iter: " << a << endl;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```